# Actionscript Event Error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, events

I try to dispatch event from actionscript class. But I get the error: "Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.events::Event@9f849c1 to mx.events.FlexEvent."

Here is my code:
MXML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" applicationComplete="init(event)">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import com.testing.package.MyASClass;

        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        public var sv:MyASClass;

        protected function init(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            sv = new MyASClass();
            sv.addEventListener("myevent",mainfunc);
            sv.myfunc();
        }

        protected function mainfunc(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            trace("receive event");
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Actionscript file:

```
package com.testing.package
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;

public class MyASClass extends Sprite
{
    public function MyASClass()
    {

    }

    public function myfunc():void
    {
        dispatch();
    }

    private function dispatch():void
    {
        dispatchEvent(new Event("myevent"));
    }
}
}
```

Why the error occur? How can I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: So try to use `Event` instead of `FlexEvent` , like : `function init(event:Event)` and `function mainfunc(event:Event)`

Comment: Thanks Cherniv. Problem solved. You just save my life.

Answer (score 1):

//Solution is need replace FlexEvent into Event

`protected function mainfunc(event:Event):void{
   trace("receive event");
}`